# send form values to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have installed MySQLdb in python2.7(64bit), I want to know how I can send form values to MySQL database.

Comment: Hi Madhur, just so you understand why people have voted you down (I did not do that), your question does not show that you have done any work to find the information yourself. Maybe you have read a tutorial and tried hard. If not, please do a Google search and try for yourself, then ask a question telling us what you've done so far.

Answer (score 3):

Start with reading.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial01/
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial02/
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial03/
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial04/

Once you've understood that then you can look at the forms documentation (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/) and the models documentation (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/)